# Query conversion from SQL Server to firebird (UPDATE with inner join)

Tags: sql, sql-update, inner-join, firebird, firebird2.5

I have the following Query in SQL Server that does not seem to run in firebird.

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET FIELD1 = XFER.FIELD2
FROM COMPANY
INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS XFER
ON TABLE1.FIELD1 = XFER.FIELD1 WHERE FIELD1 not like 'STRING1%'
```

How would I convert this to firebird?  If I leave it as is it gives me the error "Token unknown" on the from.

Comment: What exactly is the use of `company` in your query? There is no condition to restrict between company and table2, which effectively makes that a cartesian product, and you don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Firebird allows updates with joins.  You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE COMPANY
    SET FIELD1 = (SELECT FIELD2
                  FROM XFER
                  WHERE COMPANY.FIELD1 = XFER.FIELD1
                 )
    WHERE FIELD1 not like 'STRING1%' AND
          EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM XFER WHERE COMPANY.FIELD1 = XFER.FIELD1);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I missed marking this as the answer I used.

Answer (score 2):

The Firebird syntax of [`update`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-update) does not allow a `from` clause. Instead you should use [`merge`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-merge):

```
merge into table1
   using (select table2.field1, table2.field2 
          from company
          inner join table2 on company1.id = table2.companyid -- made up condition missing in your question
          where table2.field1 not like 'STRING1%'
         ) src 
   on table1.field1 = src.field1
   when matched then 
       update set table1.field1 = src.field2
```